# How to prevent accordion component from closing?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `mat-accordion`. I also request data from the server every second. And because of this, when I try to open the accordion component, it immediately closes.

Is it possible to prevent the accordion from closing, given if I will receive data from the server every second?

ts:

```
  load() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this._orders.getAllOrders())
    ).subscribe(orders => {
      this.orders = orders
    }, error => {
      this._toast.error(error.error.message);
    })
  }
```

html:

```
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let order of orders" multi>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{order.name}}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: try to use trackBy https://medium.com/@jinalshah999/trackby-with-ngfor-directives-in-angular-application-bd4d0db288eb

Comment: Can you provide sample demo with existing behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out this.

```
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let order of orders; trackBy:trackByIdentity" multi>
  ........
</mat-accordion>
```

in ts

```
trackByIdentity(index, item){
     return item.name; 
  }
```